# How can I check if a value starts with 'A2' in smarty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smarty

**Question:**
How can I check if a value starts with `'A2'`, `'A7'`, and so on. And if the value is 'A2' only show all the rows where `'$aWoning.Woning_Bouwnr'` starts with `'A2'`? Since i'm new to Smarty I really don't know what to do right now.

**Code/ Html:**

```
<table id="bouwnummers-table" class="table table-hover table-striped">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Bouwnummer</th>
                                <th>Woningtype</th>
                                <th>Woonopp.</th>
                                <th>Prijs vanaf</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {foreach $aWoningen as $aWoning}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{$aWoning.Woning_Bouwnr}</td>
                                    <td>{$aWoning.Projectwoning_Titel}</td>
                                    <td>{$aWoning.Woning_WoonOpp} m&sup2;</td>
                                    {*<td>{$aWoning.Woning_Adres|escape}</td>*}
                                    <td>
                                        {if $aWoning.Woning_Prijs!=0}
                                            {if $aWoning.Verkocht!=1}
                                                {$aWoning.Woning_Prijs|escape:"html"|lv_hele_euro}
                                            {else}
                                                Verkocht
                                            {/if}
                                        {else}
                                            n.n.b.
                                        {/if}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="{if $aWoning.Verkocht==1}status-verkocht{elseif $aWoning.Optie==1}status-optie{else}status-beschikbaar{/if}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square"></i>
                                        {if $aWoning.Verkocht==1}
                                            Verkocht
                                        {elseif $aWoning.Optie==1}
                                            In Optie
                                        {else}
                                            Beschikbaar
                                        {/if}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {/foreach}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could do

```
{if $value|strpos:'A2' !== false && $value|strpos:'A2' === '0'}
```

if return '0' position means it is start with A2 in the string

or a better approach

```
{if $value|strstr:'A2' && $value|strpos:'A2' === '0'}
```

use `strstr` to check true or false instead of `strpos`

Answer (score 1):

As in php, use strpos

```
{if $yourVarToCheck|strpos:"A2"!== false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Smarty can use "normal" php-functions.

Like this:

```
{if $yourVarToCheck|strstr:"A2"}
    //your code here
{/if}
```

Comment: That will return false positives if  the string is something like "B1 Theme A2"